# In Numpy, how can I obtain an equivalent to an arr percentile, but including negative numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, percentile

I couldn't make a better title. Let me explain:

Numpy has the percentile() function, which calculates the Nth percentile of any array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(0, 10)

print(arr)
print(np.percentile(arr, 80))

>>> [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>>> 7.2
```

Which is great - 7.2 marks the 80th percentile on that array.

How can I obtain the same percentile type of calculation, but find out the Nth percentile of both extremities of an array (the positive and negative numbers)?

For example, my array may be:

`[-10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]`

So I place them in a number line, it would go from -10 to 10. I like to get the Nth percentile that marks extremities of that number line. For 90th percentile, the output could look like -8.1 and 7.5, for example, since since 90% of the values in the array fall within that range, and the remaining 10% are lower than -8.1 or greater than 7.5.

I made these numbers up of course, just for illustrating what I'm trying to calculate.

Is there any NumPy method for obtaining such boundaries?

Please let me know if I can explain or clarify further, I know this is a complicated question to ask and I'm trying my best to make it clear. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like

```py
import numpy as np

def extremities(array, pct):
    # assert 50 <= pct <= 100
    return np.percentile(array, [100 - pct, pct])

arr = np.arange(-10, 10)
print(extremities(arr, 90)) # [-8.1, 7.1]
```

Comment: What about return np.percentile(array, [50 -pct/2, 50 + pct/2]) ? With this formula, it would be possible to use 0 <= pct <= 100.